# ImportError: No module named bs4 - despite bs4 and BeautifulSoup being installed

Tags: python, macos

I downloaded Python 3.7 and am  running a script with "`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`" and am receiving the following error on execution;

> "File "myscript.py", line 3, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ImportError: No module named bs4"

When I type "`pip3 install bs4`" or "`pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`" in the terminal I get the following;

> "Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (0.0.1) Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   (from bs4) (4.6.3)"

Executing "`import bs4`" and "`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`" in IDLE don't error out.

Any idea about what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Just `pip install bs4`. 
Probably, you are maintaining different versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have more than one version of python, if so add the path of python 3.7 in the system setting and try removing the older python if possible
and then pip install BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with importing bs4. There is a similar question with many answers. I tried many things and nothing worked but when I installed poetry [https://python-poetry.org/ ]
$ poetry add pendulum
It sorted dependencies for me so I was able to import bs4.